# Is there a difference between dynamically allocated pointer to structure and statically allocated pointer to structure in C?

Tags: c, scope, queue, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was practicing queues and when I tried to created one like this

```
struct queue
{
  struct node *front;
  struct node *rear;
};
struct queue *q;
```

and the function that creates the queue

```
void create_queue(struct queue *q)
{
  q -> rear = NULL;
  q -> front = NULL;
}
```

it failed at runtime but when I allocated the pointer to the queue inside the function dynamically
it worked.
like this

```
struct queue* queue_create(void)
{
  struct queue* q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  q->rear=NULL;
  q->front=NULL;    
}
```

Comment: You should enable your compiler's warnings about using uninitialized pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function

```
struct queue* queue_create(void)
{
  struct queue* q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  q->rear=NULL;
  q->front=NULL;    
}
```

You are not allocating a pointer dynamically as you are saying. The pointer q is a local variable of the function that will not be alive after exiting the function.

What you are allocating dynamically is an object of the type struct queue. The address of the allocated object is assigned to the local pointer.

Also what you need is to return the pointer  from the function.

```
struct queue* queue_create(void)
{
  struct queue* q = (struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  q->rear=NULL;
  q->front=NULL;    

  return q;
}
```

Otherwise there will be a memory leak.

As for this declaration of a pointer in the file scope

```
struct queue *q;
```

then it is initialized as a null pointer. So using the null pointer in this function to access memory

```
void create_queue(struct queue *q)
{
  q -> rear = NULL;
  q -> front = NULL;
}
```

invokes undefined behavior.

That is what you need to allocate dynamically is an object of the structure type. Where there will be declared a pointer that will point to the allocated object is in fact unimportant. What is important is the pointer must point to a valid object of the structure type. In this case using the pointer you can change data members of the object pointed to by the pointer.

Comment: for the first part, I copied an older version of the code, the return statement exists in the final code but still didn't work. for the second part, is declaring the  pointer in the structure already initialized it to null? so assigning it to null again results in undefined behavior? this what I get from your answer. please correct me if I'm wrong and thanks for answering.

Comment: @محمدابوالنجا You declared a pointer in the file scope struct queue *q;. This declaration is equivalent to struct queue *q = NULL; You may not use this null pointer to access memory like  q -> rear = NULL;

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
struct queue
{
  struct node *front;
  struct node *rear;
};
struct queue *q;
```

creates a `NULL` pointer to `struct queue`. It does *not* allocate an instance of this struct (unlike your code which allocates memory dynamically).

So when you call `create_queue()` on this `NULL` pointer, you (naturally) get `SIGSEGV`.

To statically allocate an instance of `struct queue`, do this:

```
struct queue q;
```

Then you can initialize it with `create_queue(&q)`.

P.S. The statically allocated `struct queue` will already be zero-initialized, so calling `create_queue()` on that instance is actually a no-op.

Comment: is there a link you could point me to that outlines when / what entities are initialized to 0 by the compiler?

Comment: I guess what I’m asking is, are these rules the same for C? I was never clear on that and I’ve been unable to find an answer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization